# Разные файлы gitignore для разных удаленных репозиториев

Tags: git, github

Имеется два удаленных репозитория git (на github и heroku). Вопрос такой: возможно ли для каждого из них использовать отдельный .gitignore файл в локальном репозитории для того чтоб   выбирать какие части проекта отправлять в каждый. Например на github репозиторий отправлять только собственный код, а на heroku - готовый проект со всеми зависимостями (c bootstrap'ом, jQuery и т.д.).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10475317 ответ на вопрос нашел здесь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пользуетесь ruby on rails, то посмотрите в сторону gem'ов jquery-rails и twitter-bootstrap-rails. Если node.js, то в сторону аналогичных npm'ов. Если уж так вышло, что для какой-то библиотеки нет gem/npm, а хранить исходный код чужих проектов в своём репозитории не хочется, то вы можете либо прописать загрузку этой клиентской библиотеки с какого-нибудь открытого CDN. Если и там не оказалось, можете сделать submodule, и указать только ссылку на другой репозиторий, хотя это далеко не всегда удобно, ибо зачастую уже собранных библиотек там нет, а только части. Выбирайте по вкусу.